# jenkins gradle package not found

Tags: maven, groovy, jenkins, gradle, build.gradle

so I have project that I'm migrating from maven to gradle, and I'm successfully able to run gradle init and gradle build on my local machine (mac os yosemite 10.10.3). However, when I attempt to build the project via jenkins, I get the following error:

```
/data/jenkins-master/tools/hudson.plugins.gradle.GradleInstallation/Gradle_2.5/bin/gradle build
:compileJava
/data/jenkins master/jobs/myproject/workspace/src/main/java/com/aaron/web/RawFileServicesRestEndpoint.java:3: error: package com.aaron.web.generated does not exist
import com.aaron.web.generated.Response;
                                     ^
/data/jenkins-master/jobs/myproject/workspace/src/main/java/com/aaron/web/RawFileServicesHelper.java:4: error: package com.aaron.web.generated does not exist
import com.aaron.web.generated.Response;
                                     ^
/data/jenkins-master/jobs/myproject/workspace/src/main/java/com/aaron/web/RawFileServicesHelper.java:5: error: package com.aaron.web.generated does not exist
import com.aaron.web.generated.ResponseCode;
                                     ^
/data/jenkins-master/jobs/myproject/workspace/src/main/java/com/aaron/web/RawFileServicesRestEndpoint.java:30: error: cannot find symbol## Heading ##
    public Response prepareFile(@PathParam("code") String code) {
           ^
  symbol:   class Response
  location: class RawFileServicesRestEndpoint
/data/jenkins-master/jobs/myproject/workspace/src/main/java/com/aaron/web/RawFileServicesHelper.java:35: error: cannot find symbol
    public Response prepareFile(String code, String clientAddr) {
           ^
  symbol:   class Response
  location: class RawFileServicesHelper
/data/jenkins-master/jobs/myproject/workspace/src/main/java/com/aaron/web/RawFileServicesSoapEndpoint.java:3: error: package com.aaron.web.generated does not exist
import com.aaron.web.generated.RawFileServices;
                                     ^
/data/jenkins-master/jobs/myproject/workspace/src/main/java/com/aaron/web/RawFileServicesSoapEndpoint.java:4: error: package com.aaron.web.generated does not exist
import com.aaron.web.generated.Response;
                                     ^
/data/jenkins-master/jobs/myproject/workspace/src/main/java/com/aaron/web/RawFileServicesSoapEndpoint.java:20: error: cannot find symbol
public class RawFileServicesSoapEndpoint implements RawFileServices {
                                                    ^
  symbol: class RawFileServices
/data/jenkins-master/jobs/myproject/workspace/src/main/java/com/aaron/web/RawFileServicesSoapEndpoint.java:28: error: cannot find symbol
    public Response prepareFile(String code) {
           ^
  symbol:   class Response
  location: class RawFileServicesSoapEndpoint
/data/jenkins-master/jobs/myproject/workspace/src/main/java/com/aaron/web/RawFileServicesHelper.java:44: error: cannot find symbol
            Response response = new Response();
            ^
  symbol:   class Response
  location: class RawFileServicesHelper
/data/jenkins-master/jobs/myproject/workspace/src/main/java/com/aaron/web/RawFileServicesHelper.java:44: error: cannot find symbol
            Response response = new Response();
                                    ^
  symbol:   class Response
  location: class RawFileServicesHelper
/data/jenkins-master/jobs/myproject/workspace/src/main/java/com/aaron/web/RawFileServicesHelper.java:47: error: cannot find symbol
                response.setCode(ResponseCode.CODE_NOT_FOUND);
                                 ^
  symbol:   variable ResponseCode
  location: class RawFileServicesHelper
/data/jenkins-master/jobs/myproject/workspace/src/main/java/com/aaron/web/RawFileServicesHelper.java:50: error: cannot find symbol
                response.setCode(ResponseCode.SAMPLE_NOT_VALID);
                                 ^
  symbol:   variable ResponseCode
  location: class RawFileServicesHelper
/data/jenkins-master/jobs/myproject/workspace/src/main/java/com/aaron/web/RawFileServicesHelper.java:75: error: cannot find symbol
                    response.setCode(ResponseCode.COMPLETED);
                                     ^
  symbol:   variable ResponseCode
  location: class RawFileServicesHelper
/data/jenkins-master/jobs/myproject/workspace/src/main/java/com/aaron/web/RawFileServicesHelper.java:98: error: cannot find symbol
                        response.setCode(ResponseCode.ABORTED);
                                         ^
  symbol:   variable ResponseCode
  location: class RawFileServicesHelper
/data/jenkins-master/jobs/myproject/workspace/src/main/java/com/aaron/web/RawFileServicesHelper.java:101: error: cannot find symbol
                        response.setCode(ResponseCode.IN_PROCESS);
                                         ^
  symbol:   variable ResponseCode
  location: class RawFileServicesHelper
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
16 errors
:compileJava FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':compileJava'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED
```

Here is my build.gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'maven'

group = 'com.aaron.web'
version = '1.0'

description = """"""

sourceCompatibility = 1.7
targetCompatibility = 1.7

repositories {
     maven { url "http://maven.mystuff.com/nexus/content/groups/aaron/" }
     maven { url "http://archiva.mystuff.com/repository/cms-releases" }
     maven { url "http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2" }
}
dependencies {
    compile group: 'com.google.guava', name: 'guava', version:'11.0.2'
    compile group: 'commons-io', name: 'commons-io', version:'2.0.1'
    compile group: 'org.apache.tomcat', name: 'tomcat-jdbc', version:'7.0.21'
    compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-orm', version:'4.1.6.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-web', version:'4.1.6.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'org.hibernate', name: 'hibernate-entitymanager', version:'3.4.0.GA'
    compile group: 'org.slf4j', name: 'slf4j-api', version:'1.7.12'
    compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-context', version:'4.1.6.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'mysql', name: 'mysql-connector-java', version:'5.1.10'
    compile group: 'com.sun.xml.ws', name: 'jaxws-rt', version:'2.2.10'
    compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-aspects', version:'4.1.6.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'org.aspectj', name: 'aspectjrt', version:'1.6.8'
    compile(group: 'org.jvnet.jax-ws-commons.spring', name: 'jaxws-spring', version:'1.9') {
exclude(module: 'servlet-api')
    }
    compile group: 'commons-lang', name: 'commons-lang', version:'2.4'
    compile group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', name: 'httpclient', version:'4.1.1'
    compile group: 'com.aaron', name: 'sla', version:'1.0.4'
    compile group: 'org.eclipse.jetty', name: 'jetty-webapp', version:'9.3.0.M2'
    compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-webmvc', version:'4.1.6.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'org.slf4j', name: 'slf4j-simple', version:'1.7.12'
    compile(group: 'com.sun.jersey.contribs', name: 'jersey-spring', version:'1.9') {
        exclude(module: 'spring')
        exclude(module: 'spring-core')
        exclude(module: 'spring-web')
        exclude(module: 'spring-beans')
        exclude(module: 'spring-context')
    }
    compile group: 'com.sun.jersey', name: 'jersey-server', version:'1.9'
    compile group: 'com.sun.jersey', name: 'jersey-json', version:'1.9'
    testCompile(group: 'org.mockito', name: 'mockito-core', version:'1.9.5') {
        exclude(module: 'hamcrest-core')
    }
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version:'4.12'
}
```

The os that jenkins is running on has the following specs (shown when I run the unix cmd "uname -a"):

```
Linux PRDSLHLSRVJNK05 2.6.32-220.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Tue Dec 6 19:48:22 GMT 2011 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Both systems use the same version of gradle and groovy (2.5 and 2.3.10). Any ideas on what might be causing the build to succeed on one machine and fail on the other? I'm completely at a loss after troubleshooting this for a while.

Comment: ANDROID_HOME  path exist？